# JQuery bxslider conflict

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I'm developing a website that will 3-4 sliders (bxsliders) per page, my porblem is that would like to format one by one, specialy the height and margin of the button below (http://bxslider.com/examples/manual-show-without-infinite-loop), but that field on the bxslider.css serves all sliders.

JS:

```
    $('#namesJobsMob').bxSlider({
        infiniteLoop: false,
        hideControlOnEnd: true,
        touchEnabled:true
});
        $('#missValMob').bxSlider({
        infiniteLoop: false,
        hideControlOnEnd: true,
        touchEnabled:true
});
```

CSS:

```
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a {
margin: -50px 25px;
}
```

For instance: i owuld one to have margin margin: -50px 25px; and another margin: -10px 40px;

Answer (score 0):

When I want to have multiple bxsliders in a page, I wrap them in divs one by one. For instance:

```
<div id="firstslider">
<ul id="slider1">
<li>image1</li>
<li>image2</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="secondslider">
<ul id="slider2">
<li>image3</li>
<li>image4</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

After that you can target a specific .bx-wrapper this way:

```
#firstslider .bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a {
margin: -50px 25px;
}
```